# creating an npm console application thats "installable" (like yeoman or gulp or grunt etc..)

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, npm, package

I'm quite new to the whole NPM-stuff, however, I would like to create a new package that should be able to run as a console-app (like gulp and grunt).

So basically what I would like to do is making it possible to run

```
npm install -g mypackage
```

and then

```
mypackage
```

and that would then kick off the console application.

I have been using `npm init` to init my new package, I have also created the entry point (in my case app.js), and node app.js runs fine.

I have also used `npm pack` to create a package and `npm install {path to my .tgz}`.

This is my app.js:

```
console.log('Hi from NodeJS');
```

Nothing fancy so far.

The package is called "mypackage"
The problem is that when I type:
`mypackage` in my console the console application doesn't run.

Any ideas?

Br,
Inx

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [bin](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin).

> To install one or more executable files to `PATH`, you shoul supply a
>   bin field in your `package.json` which is a map of command name to
>   local file name. On install, npm will symlink that file into
>   prefix/bin for global installs, or ./node_modules/.bin/ for local
>   installs.

For example, grunt-cli has this:

```
"bin": {
  "grunt": "bin/grunt"
},
```

Where `bin/grunt` is a js file (yet without an extension defined).

P.S. If you're planning to ship this as a global package, don't forget to set [preferGlobal](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#preferglobal).

Comment: Hi!
Ok, after I have been doing some tests..
Basically what this does is executing/opening the file/program thats located in bin/grunt?
So if I had my npm console application.. I would basically put the .exe in and use:
"bin": {
  "mypackage": "bin/mypackage.exe"
},

?

I just tried the above with:
"bin": {
  "mypackage": "bin/mypackage"
},
Where the bin/mypackage file container a simple console.log.. However.. after installing the package and running "mypackage" in my console.. I got asked to choose a program to open the file with, since the file was unrecoginzed by my OS.

Comment: @lnx51 you don't need any exe files, the path you specify in bin is a path to the js file. So having `"bin": { "mypack": "path/to/file.js" }` in `package.json` + instaleld globally + executing `mypack` would be the same as `node path/to/file.js`